# Material-ui AppBar component not changing background-color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I have been in this error for quite a while now in my React application but can't seem to find a solution nor a logical explanation. I'm using Material-UI v6 and styled-components.
I have this styled component (AppBar.styled.js):

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { AppBar } from "@mui/material";

const StyledAppBar = styled(AppBar)`
  margin: 20px; //${(props) => props.theme.palette.tertiary.main};
  background-color: darkorange;
`;

export default StyledAppBar;
```

And curiously, the margin property is correctly applied to the appbar but the background-color is not:
[image]

I can't seem to figure out why nor a solution. Can some one care to exaplain what is happening and how can I solve this? I already tried to add the `StyledEngineProvider` but still no changes. This is how the App.js looks like:

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import GlobalStyles from "./components/styles/Global";
import darkTheme from "./components/styles/darkTheme";
import lightTheme from "./components/styles/lightTheme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./pages/Home";
import HelpPage from "./pages/Help";
import NavigationBar from "./components/NavigationBar";

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
     { path: "/", element: <HomePage /> },
     { path: "/help", element: <HelpPage /> },
    ]);

  function App() {
    const theme = lightTheme;
    return (
     <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <Fragment>
       <GlobalStyles></GlobalStyles>
        <NavigationBar></NavigationBar>
        <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>
     </Fragment>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
 }

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which was to use the "!important" keyword but this is not recommended. But there is another trick: the correct and working solution is to use `<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>...</StyledEngineProvider>` in the returning JSX code in the App.js.
It is also **recommended** by the official documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to achive this is by changing it from theme. You can see in this example.

https://www.brainstormcreative.co.uk/material-ui/how-to-change-the-material-ui-appbar-background-color/

Comment: The thing is that I want to use styled-component. That example uses the built-in makeStyles function from material-ui. Thank you for the suggestion tho

Comment: If you want to achieve this with a styled component, then you have to go with ! important.